# How to apply function to cell depending upon cell value in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    Size count Density
1  large    12      NA
2  medium     7      NA
3  small     4      NA
4  large    68      NA
5  medium    53      NA
6  small    25      NA
7  large   139      NA
8  medium    85      NA
9  small    47      NA
10 large   148      NA
11 medium    88      NA
12 small    39      NA
```

I am trying to calculate the density column. So, if the size is large, I want to divide the count by 225. If size is medium, divide count by 144, and if size is small, divide count by 49.

I have no clue how I would go about doing this so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to make look-up tables for things like this. I find it is easy to check and debug:

```
density_lookup = data.frame(
  size = c("large", "medium", "small"),
  denominator = c(225, 144, 49)
)

## Inspect, make sure it looks right
density_lookup
#     size denominator
# 1  large         225
# 2 medium         144
# 3  small          49

# With base R
your_data = merge(your_data, density_lookup, by = "size", all.x = TRUE)
your_data$Density = with(your_data, count / denominator)

# with dplyr
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  left_join(density_lookup, by = "size") %>%
  mutate(Density = count / denominator)
```

You could also use named vectors or `ifelse()` statements, but I like this approach because it generalizes up very well - you can match on multiple columns, if needed. You can store the lookup in a CSV file if you want to share it with non-R-users.

Answer (score 1):

If the classes are not too large, you can use `ifelse()` althought **@GregorThomas** solution is more practical:

```
#Base R
df$Density <- ifelse(df$Size=='large',df$count/225,
                     ifelse(df$Size=='medium',df$count/144,df$count/49))
```

Output:

```
     Size count    Density
1   large    12 0.05333333
2  medium     7 0.04861111
3   small     4 0.08163265
4   large    68 0.30222222
5  medium    53 0.36805556
6   small    25 0.51020408
7   large   139 0.61777778
8  medium    85 0.59027778
9   small    47 0.95918367
10  large   148 0.65777778
11 medium    88 0.61111111
12  small    39 0.79591837
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Size = c("large", "medium", "small", "large", 
"medium", "small", "large", "medium", "small", "large", "medium", 
"small"), count = c(12L, 7L, 4L, 68L, 53L, 25L, 139L, 85L, 47L, 
148L, 88L, 39L), Density = c(0.0533333333333333, 0.0486111111111111, 
0.0816326530612245, 0.302222222222222, 0.368055555555556, 0.510204081632653, 
0.617777777777778, 0.590277777777778, 0.959183673469388, 0.657777777777778, 
0.611111111111111, 0.795918367346939)), row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

This one also works

```
within(df1, Density <- count / c("large" = 225, "medium" = 144, "small" = 49)[Size])
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Size   count Density
   <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 large     12  0.0533
 2 medium     7  0.0486
 3 small      4  0.0816
 4 large     68  0.302 
 5 medium    53  0.368 
 6 small     25  0.510 
 7 large    139  0.618 
 8 medium    85  0.590 
 9 small     47  0.959 
10 large    148  0.658 
11 medium    88  0.611 
12 small     39  0.796
```